# Mac OS X Mavericks - IconServicesAgent memory usage started to grow (leaks?)

Tags: macos, virtualbox, memory, vagrant, memory-leaks

Recently I found that `IconServicesAgent` began to grow up to **130-200Mb** but before it was max 6Mb.. 
[image]

As far as I remeber last things that I was installing were Vagrant and Virtualbox. Not sure that this is connected but anyway somehow it started to grow.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had the same problem, the problem came because I have deleted everything in the /var/folders/ which is an temporary folder, but apparently OS X is depending on a folder inside the tmp folder.

So **if you run the following command from Terminal it should go back to normal again** (at least that fixed it for me):

```
mkdir ${TMPDIR}/com.apple.IconServices
```

See this post: [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/121317/com-apple-iconservices-is-causing-high-cpu-usage-and-finder-problems-in-maverick)